# Oracle Apex Query error - ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select 
EQUIPMENT_OBJ_UID,
EQUIPMENT_CREATED_TIMESTAMP,
EQUIPMENT_CREATED_BY,
EQUIPMENT_NAME,
EQUIPMENT_STATUS,
EQUIPMENT_TYPE,
DESCRIPTION,
EQUIPMENT_OWNER,
SECONDARY_OWNER,
TERTIARY_OWNER, 
FACILITY, 
(select MAX(ENTER_STATE_TIMESTAMP) from EQUIP_STATE_HISTORY where EQUIP_STATE_HISTORY.EQUIPMENT = EQUIPMENT_NAME) as "LAST_STATE_CHANGE", 
(select EQUIP_STATE_HISTORY.CREATED_BY from EQUIP_STATE_HISTORY where EQUIP_STATE_HISTORY.EQUIPMENT = EQUIPMENT_NAME and ENTER_STATE_TIMESTAMP = (select MAX(ENTER_STATE_TIMESTAMP) from EQUIP_STATE_HISTORY where EQUIP_STATE_HISTORY.EQUIPMENT = EQUIPMENT_NAME)) as "LAST_STATE_CHANGE_USER",
(select count(EQP_ISSUE_OBJ_UID) from EQP_ISSUE_OBJ
where EQP_ISSUE_TOOL = EQUIPMENT_NAME
and EQP_ISSUE_STATUS != 'Closed' and EQP_ISSUE_STATUS != 'Cancelled') as "OPEN_ISSUES",
(select STATE_CHANGE_REASON from EQUIP_STATE_HISTORY where EQUIPMENT = EQUIPMENT_NAME and ENTER_STATE_TIMESTAMP = (select MAX(ENTER_STATE_TIMESTAMP) from EQUIP_STATE_HISTORY where EQUIPMENT = EQUIPMENT_NAME)) as "DOWN_REASON", 
(select MAX(EQUIPMENT_PM_LOG.CREATED_TIMESTAMP) from EQUIPMENT_PM_LOG where (ACTIVITY_TYPE = 'Light Bulb Change') and EQUIPMENT_PM_LOG.EQUIPMENT = EQUIPMENT_OBJ.EQUIPMENT_NAME) as "LAST_BULB_CHANGE", 
(select EQUIPMENT_PM_LOG.LIGHT_BULB_EXPECTED_HRS from EQUIPMENT_PM_LOG where 
ACTIVITY_TYPE = 'Light Bulb Change' and EQUIPMENT_PM_LOG.EQUIPMENT = EQUIPMENT_OBJ.EQUIPMENT_NAME and 
EQUIPMENT_PM_LOG.CREATED_TIMESTAMP = (select MAX(EQUIPMENT_PM_LOG.CREATED_TIMESTAMP) from EQUIPMENT_PM_LOG where ACTIVITY_TYPE = 'Light Bulb Change' and EQUIPMENT_PM_LOG.EQUIPMENT = EQUIPMENT_OBJ.EQUIPMENT_NAME)) as "LIGHT_BULB_EXPECTED_HRS" 
from EQUIPMENT_OBJ
```

The above query works fine when running in the SQL Commands but giving error ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row in Oracle apex application interactive report
Please help, Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Logging exception:
Sqlerrm: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
Backtrace: ORA-06512: at "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET", line 4278
ORA-06512: at "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET", line 11472

Comment: What steps have you taken to try to isolate the issue? Have you tried a smaller version of the query (assuming that's possible) to see if you get the same issue.  Try looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Probably you have two rows with the same max timestamp in your EQUIP_STATE_HISTORY or EQUIPMENT_PM_LOG tables.

Comment: Note that APEX's SQL Commands only fetches a fixed number of records; to reproduce the problem there you would need to increase the fetch count.

Comment: I don't have a sandbox to test different scenarios but I tired running this query in SQL Query editor and it is returning multiple rows as expected.

Comment: May I know how to increase fetch count?